# VS2005: What are SQL Server projects used for?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005

When I open up VS2005 I can see one of the options for projects is "SQL Server Project"?

What would be the purpose of these projects?  Would it be a place to put business logic for your application such that it could serve business objects to an app, or is that completely off-track?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2005/03/08/389860.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> You can use .NET Framework languages in addition to the Transact-SQL
> programming language to create database objects such as stored
> procedures and triggers, and to retrieve and update data for Microsoft
> SQL Server 2005 databases

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8dbfz8s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

hope it helps